# Why won't my windows 10 computer boot Ubuntu 16.04 from a usb?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows, 16.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 onto my laptop, which doesn't have a disc drive, so I tried to boot from a live USB. I have followed several tutorials, used various different programs to burn the ISO to my USB, and even searched the all knowing google, but my computer still wont boot from it. I was able to get it to recognize my USB only once in BIOS, and even then it still completely ignored my USB and booted to windows, after I set the USB as default booting priority! I also tested this on my desktop, and a windows 7 computer, all with the same results. Is there a setting in windows I need to disable? or did I just make the USB wrong every time?

Comment: You must select to boot from that USB in your BIOS/UEFI boot menu. And your BIOS/UEFI has to be capable of booting from USB, there might be some old models that can't do that. You also have to ensure that SecureBoot is disabled if your BIOS/UEFI has such a setting.

Comment: I had already given the USB boot priority, but I just tried disabling SecureBoot, and it didn't help. I guess its possible that I can't boot from USB, but I doubt it, I bought this computer last November.

Comment: I can't tell you. Can you verify that the USB drive is bootable on any other computer? If it works there, it's either your hardware or your BIOS/UEFI that can/wants not to work. You could also try to generate a bootable USB drive of any other system and test that, but I doubt you get different results. This would make the question somehow off-topic here though, I think. Anyway, the guys over at [su] probably know more about such a general problem which is not directly related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I checked with Acer, and I can boot from USB. I tried it on other computers as well, with the same result. I think its the USB that's causing the problems. I will check at Super User, thanks.